# Regex in rewerite rule in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying to redirect some urls of my old website after my migration , urls that need to be redirected are:

**first block**:

```
   /fr/YYYY/mm/dd/
   /fr/YYYY/mm/
   /fr/YYYY
```

target:

```
   blog/
```

**Second block**:

```
    /fr/tag/tag1
    /fr/tag/tag4
    /fr/tag/tag3
    /fr/tag/tag2
```

target:

```
   blog/targetpage
```

**Third block**

```
   fr/categorie/categoryName/
```

target

```
   blog/categoryName
```

For the first block I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^fr/d{4}/(.*) /blog [R=301]
```

It does only work for pattern like: fr/2015 but not fr/2015/12/02

I tried another regex https://regex101.com/r/4oZpxX/1 but I do not how to write it htaccess style.

Could please help me with this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For your first block, `\/fr\/(\d{4})\/?(\d{2})?\/?(\d{2})?` will recognize all of those date formats correctly.

- `\d{#}` recognizes a string of # digits
- `?` after `\/` and `\d{#}` makes them optional

For the second and third block I need more information about what kind of strings the "tags" and "categories" are.